# How can this delete to prevent the memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I really really thank the people who give me the help.Thank you!

```
struct MyImage
{
    BYTE* pImage;
    int width;
    int heigth;
};
MyImage* pMyImage = new MyImage;
pMyImage->pImage = new BYTE[width * heigth];
```

should I do like this?

```
delete [] pMyImage->pImage;
```

or should I do like this?

```
delete[] pMyImage->pImage;
delete pMyImage;
```

hope for your ideas and Thanks.

```
MyImage* transform(Bitmap &gdiImage)
{
MyImage* image=new MyImage;//新建一个MyImage

int height=gdiImage.GetHeight();
int width=gdiImage.GetWidth();

image->pImage=new BYTE[height*width];//为存储灰度图像数据分配内存

image->height=height;
image->width=width;

Color temp;
for(int y = 0;y < height; ++y)
    for(int x = 0;x < width; ++x)
    {
        //获取当前GDI+图像坐标所指向的像素的颜色
        gdiImage.GetPixel(x, y, &temp);
        //将这个像素的灰度值赋给灰度图像对应的内存中的相应的字节
        *(image->pImage + y * width + x) = transformPixel(temp.GetValue());
    }
return image;
}
```

My code is as below, this function translate a gdiImage to a struct MyImage.
as a firend say, as follows, I can not new MyImage and new pImage,the element of MyImage.
what should I do? thank you

Comment: Second one, one `new` must always be matched with one `delete` (once you have no need for the data anymore, of course).

Comment: And ideally you would have `delete [] pImage;` in `MyImage`'s destructor. Each instance owns its `pImage`, so is responsible for clearing it up.

Comment: For each `new` you need a `delete`. For each `new[]` you need a `delete[]`.

Comment: None of the two, since the premise is wrong in the first place. As noted by others `MyImage` should be responsible for allocating (and thus also for freeing) the data for `MyImage::pImage`. And the storage for a `MyImage` should in turn probably not be allocated dynamically at all. So the first `new` is arguable and the second one is misplaced.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<BYTE*>`.

Comment: Phew I'm glad you put those comments in there, that clarifies things! :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd implement constructor and destructor in MyImage:

```
struct MyImage
{
    MyImage() : pImage(nullptr), width(0), height(0)
    {
    }

    ~MyImage()
    {
        delete [] pImage;
    }
    BYTE* pImage;
    int width;
    int heigth;
};
```

Generally, it's better to be made a class where pImage, width and height are private members.

Comment: This class also needs a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to be safe.

Answer (score 6):

Your second alternative would be correct, but to avoid that you can get calling `delete` (e.g. forgetting to do so) wrong in the first place, I suggest to use appropriate tools which take care of that.

For instance, chances are that your dynamically allocated `BYTE` array might be a good candidate for a `std::vector`. The `MyWidget` could be managed by some kind of smart pointer, e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or the like. Or maybe you don't even need to allocate it dynamically at all but can just create it on the stack and then pass the address around should you need it. So, maybe something like this:

```
// An example function dealing with images. This one draws it.
void draw(MyImage *img);

struct MyImage
{
    std::vector<BYTE> image;
    int width;
    int heigth;
};

MyImage myImage;
myImage.image.resize(width * height);
// ...
draw(&myImage);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second option is the good one :

```
delete[] pMyImage->pImage;
delete pMyImage;
```

**A `new` must always be matched with a `delete` and a `new[]` must always be matched with a `delete[]`.**

`MyImage` should be responsible for allocating/freeing this data to prevent any error...

You could place the `delete[] pMyImage->pImage;` in the `MyImage` destructor :

```
MyImage::~MyImage()
{
    delete [] pImage;
}
```

Finally, I suggest you to take a look to the smart pointers in c++. For example to `std::unique_ptr` :

> The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:
>
> - unique_ptr managing the object is destroyed
> - unique_ptr managing the object is assigned another pointer via operator=() or reset().
>
> The object is destroyed using a potentially user-supplied deleter by calling Deleter(ptr). The deleter calls the destructor of the object and dispenses the memory.

Something like that :

```
#include <memory>

struct MyImage
{
    std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> m_Image;
    int width;
    int heigth;
};

MyImage* pMyImage = new MyImage;
pMyImage->m_Image= std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]>( new BYTE[ width * height ] );
```

Comment: Why the condition in the destructor? I'd expect `delete` and `delete[]` to accept the null pointer and ignore it, and a quick search on http://cppreference.com seems to confirms this.

Comment: No worries, I was just wondering if I had missed some reason to perform the test yourself.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I added a little more code and I corrected that.

Comment: @user2590664 I tried this code on VS2012 and it works. You should consider a solution of this type of with a `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is

```
delete[] pMyImage->pImage;
delete pMyImage;
```

You must match a `new` with a `delete`, and a `new[]` with a `delete[]` (with a few exceptions, e.g. when you know a library handles memory itself, like Qt and its parent/child system)

Answer (score 1):

The second one. Any memory that you manually allocate with `new` or `new[]` has to be manually deallocated using `delete` or `delete[]` respectively.